# Chrome kills my 16gb ram new iMac but runs fine on 2gb 5yr old Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, memory, google-chrome

I like using Chrome as it has a lot of the plugins I need for Web Dev. However, it kills my new iMac - having more than 6 tabs open affects the performance dramatically.

Oddly enough this does not happen on my 5 year old Air that only has 2gb of ram.

Why is this and what could I do to fix the iMac?

Comment: well you macbook air has an SSD so write in/outs are way faster

Comment: I agree with Macmaniman, it seems likely to be that your MacBook Air hs an SSD and your iMac doesn't. It might help to share some screenshots of Activity Monitor from each machine?

Comment: Are you opening the same tabs on each machine? Have you looked using the developer tools if you have loops or other heavy task?